# Apache-Spark: method in foreach doesn't work

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jts

I read file from `HDFS`, which contains `x1,x2,y1,y2` representing a `envelope` in [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Envelope.html).

I would like to use those data to build [STRtree](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/index.html) in `foreach`.

```
val inputData = sc.textFile(inputDataPath).cache()

val strtree = new STRtree

inputData.foreach(line => {val array = line.split(",").map(_.toDouble);val e = new Envelope(array(0),array(1),array(2),array(3)) ;
  println("envelope is " + e);
  strtree.insert(e,
  new Rectangle(array(0),array(1),array(2),array(3)))})
```

As you can see, I also print the `e` object.

To my surprise, when I log the size of `strtree`, it is zero! It seems that `insert` method make no senses here.

By the way, if I write hard code some test data line by line, the `strtree` can be built well.

One more thing, those project is packed into jar and submitted in the `spark-shell`.

So, why does the method in `foreach` not work ?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to collect() to do this:

```
inputData.collect().foreach(line => {
 ... // your code
})
```

You can do this (for avoiding `collect`ing all data):

```
val pairs = inputData.map(line => {
    val array = line.split(",").map(_.toDouble);
    val e = new Envelope(array(0),array(1),array(2),array(3)) ;
    println("envelope is " + e);
    (e, new Rectangle(array(0),array(1),array(2),array(3)))
}

pairs.collect().foreach(pair => {
    strtree.insert(pair._1, pair._2)
}
```

Comment: Yes, calling  `collect()` is right. However, `collect` will **Return an array that contains all of the elements in this RDD.** and if the dataset is too big to fit in the memory, how to do ?

Comment: Your `strTree` data structure has to be able to ulimately fit in memory of the driver. So you can `map` the different partitions to your desired `data pair` first (which are needed for `strTree` insertion) and then do a collect in that case. Please let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: Indeed, I need to build r-tree index for large scale spatial dataset based on Apache-Spark. I am trying to use [STRtree](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/index.html), but it seems that it is not feasible. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I think if you are usecase is to have a fast search you should rather use `Hbase` to keep the data (key value pairs) and then use spark jobs to run your application logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use .map() instead of .foreach() and reassign the outcome.

Foreach does not return the outcome of applyied function. It can be used for sending data somewhere, storing to db, printing, and so on.